# Create an array from mysql with column names and values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i'm trying to create an array with PHP and MySQL, but i always get errors.

The code i'm using

```
function db_listar_usuarios(){
$link=db_connect();
$query = "select * from usuarios" or die("Problemas en el select: " . mysqli_error($link));
$result = $link->query($query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
        echo $row['nombre'] . array(;
        foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
           $col => $val;
        }
        echo "\n\n############\n";
    }
}
```

And what I want to create with this code is:

```
array(
    'john' => array('address' => 'st 123', 'age' => '25', 'surname' => 'doe'),
    'ane' => array('address' => 'av 456', 'age'=> '32', 'surname' => 'smith'),
);
```

To use then like something like this:

```
private $contacts = db_listar_usuarios();
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `but i always get errors.` -- all our crystal balls are in the shop for repairs, so we can't magically read your mind to see what your errors are.

Comment: Upvote that glorious comment. @AmalMurali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function db_listar_usuarios(){
$link=db_connect();
$query = "select * from usuarios" or die("Problemas en el select: " . mysqli_error($link));
$result = $link->query($query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
        echo $row['nombre'] . array(; // <- invalid in several ways
        foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
           $col => $val;
        }
        echo "\n\n############\n";
    }
}
```

Try:

```
function db_listar_usuarios(){
    $link = db_connect();
    $query = "select * from usuarios" or die("Problemas en el select: " . mysqli_error($link));
    $result = $link->query($query);
    $myArray = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
        $myArray[] = $row;
        print_r($myArray); // for debugging
        echo "\n\n############\n";
    }
    return $myArray;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but I can't make it work.

i've got 2 files 
server.php -> http://pastebin.com/5j54m1Mz
functions.php -> http://pastebin.com/N7jMhSBa

I want to make an API with REST and with MySQL, but it doesn't work.

Thanks you again!

Comment: @ScaZ it just occurred to me that the code was doing needless work, and doing it wrong to boot. I've updated my code with something simpler that should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, but it still not working... when I put: private $contacts = db_listar_usuarios();

PHP ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\server.php on line 7

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {            
    foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
        $users[$col] = $val;
    }
}
print_r($users);
```